# How to Dissolve Glyphosate?

Tags: biochemistry

I am a microbiologist forming a growth media which has glyphosate in it. Unfortunately, I am having troubles dissolving it in water. At a .2M solution in 200ml of water, it is not completely dissolving. Does anyone know why this is chemically happening? Even upon adjusting pH and raising temperatures, I am unable to dissolve it.
https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/glyphosate
If you have any ideas please let me know.

Comment: As written, this is a combination of "too broad" and borderline homework - in the link you give, it says the pH of a 1% solution is 2.5. You might consider narrowing the scope of the question and/or adding your thoughts to avoid closure.

Comment: Will do. Though, in all serious, this is not a homework problem. The biologist at the lab I am working at do not know why this is.

Comment: So you've got 0.2 M, which is about 34 g/L. Solubility - from your link - is in the range of 1 to 12 g/L. Your solution is supersaturated.

Answer (score 4):

This structure has a phosphonic and a carboxylic acid moieties with a minimum number of carbon atoms. As such, it should be soluble in basic water to deprotonate at least one site

Comment: + 1, this is the correct answer, but you might consider elaborating.  What exactly what do you mean by "basic water" (sodium hydroxide?  ammonium hydroxide?  some other base?)  Would recommend focusing on the molarity of the hydroxide added or the pH of the resulting solution?